# Openlayers 3.6: Getting the center of the current map view

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to get the current center of an Openlayers map in lat/lon coordinates. I've got the following event handler setup:

```
this.map.on('pointermove', function (e) {
    if (e.dragging) {
        console.log(that.map.getView().getCenter());
    }
});
```

This works, but I'm getting weird values. Here's an example:

```
[9318218.659044644, 3274618.6225819485]
```

Those are obviously not lat/lon values :) Do I need to transform this somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with openlayers but it sounds like the map is in different projection.

Check out the following on [spherical_mercator](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html), [transform](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html#OpenLayers.LonLat.transform),
[Open Layers projections](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Projection-js.html#OpenLayers.Projection)

**UPDATED**
I've done a little more research, check out this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/wms-custom-proj.html?q=transform).  Not sure what the projection your view is in.  the map in this example is in ''EPSG:21781' if you go to a js console and enter `map.getView().getCenter()` you get `[693230.7161150641, 179010.3389264635]` but if you enter `ol.proj.transform(map.getView().getCenter(), 'EPSG:21781', 'EPSG:4326')` you get `[8.658936030357363, 46.75575224283748]` hope that helps.

Comment: Doh! My map was in EPSG:3857. The following line worked for me:

`ol.proj.transform(map.getView().getCenter(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')`

Thank you!

Comment: OpenLayers looks cool.  I've only ever used google maps but I might have to play around.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are working with angular.
*Also, I would consider searching the projection of the map, instead of entering it manually.*

```js
import * as olProj from 'ol/proj'
import Map from 'ol/Map'

// ...

olProj.transform(
    this.map.getView().getCenter(),
    this.map.getView().getProjection(),
    'EPSG:4326',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update for OpenLayers 6 (assuming your map is called 'map') the following gives an array of [lon, lat] for the centre of your map's view.

```
ol.proj.toLonLat( map.getView().getCenter() )
```